# How to add help for an dynamic parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

So, I've created a cmdlet with a dynamic parameter:

```
public class MyCmdLet : IDynamicParameters
{
    public string StandbyFilePath => _standbyFilePathDynamicParameter.StandbyFilePath;
    private StandbyFilePathDynamicParameter _standbyFilePathDynamicParameter;

    public object GetDynamicParameters()
    {
        if (RecoveryState == RestoreMode.StandBy)
        {
            return _standbyFilePathDynamicParameter = new StandbyFilePathDynamicParameter();
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class StandbyFilePathDynamicParameter 
{
    [Parameter(Mandatory = true)]
    public string StandbyFilePath
    {
        get { return _standbyFilePath; }
        set { _standbyFilePath = value; }
    }

    private string _standbyFilePath;
}
```

So everything is great except, this parameter is not shown in cmdlet help. Is there anyway how to add help ?

Comment: I've not done it before so won't submit an answer / haven't had time to read the linked info in full yet; but this looks useful for you: https://info.sapien.com/index.php/scripting/scripting-help/writing-help-for-dynamic-parameters

Comment: Presumably you have [searched](http://www.google.com/search?&q=powershell+comment+based+help+dynamic+parameter) and read the results already?